# How does the ternary operator evaluate the resulting datatype?

Tags: java, type-conversion, ternary-operator

Given this piece of code

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(1);
        foo("1");
        foo(true?1:"1");
        foo(false?1:"1");
    }

    static void foo(int i){System.out.println("int");}
    static void foo(String s){System.out.println("String");}
    static void foo(Object o){System.out.println("Object");}
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
int
String
Object
Object
```

I can't understand why in the last two cases `foo(Object o)` is invoked, instead of `foo(int i)` and `foo(String s)`.
Isn't the return type for a ternary expression evaluated at runtime?

**Edit:**

What was confusing me is the assertion that

```
System.out.println((y>5) ? 21 : "Zebra");
```

compiles because (*OCA Study Guide - Sybex*):

> The *System.out.println()* does not care that the statements are completely differnt types, because it can convert both to *String*

while the point is that *println* is overloaded to accept *Object* types as input. Quite misleading, imho.

Comment: Overload resolution is always determined at compile-time.

Comment: @Radiodef OP's asking why the result of the ternary operator was `Object` and not `int` or `String` specifically.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well why should it be either `int` or `String` and not `Object`? The OP states they think the type should be evaluated at run-time and that's not true. For the result to be either `int` or `String` the condition would therefore have to be evaluated at compile-time and for most cases that's not possible. With my previous comment in mind, the program's behavior should be reasonably expected.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the book is misleading you.

Comment: @LouisWasserman and that's not the only misleading information... Another one and I'll set it on fire! And it's suggested by Oracle itself...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Isn't the return type for a ternary expression evaluated at runtime?

No, absolutely not. That would be very contrary to the way Java works, where overload resolution etc is always performed at compile-time. What would you expect to happen if you hadn't passed the result to a method, but tried to assign it to a variable? What sort of variable would you have declared?

The expression's type is governed by the rules of [JLS 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25). In both your cases, the third operand is of type `String`, leading to this being a *reference conditional expression*, so table 15.25-E is applied, with a result of `lub(Integer,Object)`. The `lub` part refers to [JLS 4.10.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4), which is fairly confusing - the type here isn't *exactly* the same as just `Object`, but in most cases it can be considered that way.

Comment: +1 for "What would you expect to happen if you hadn't passed the result to a method, but tried to assign it to a variable?"

Comment: Well, it makes sense... I was trying to find an answer by reading that paragraph, but it's still a bit confusing to me

Comment: The rules for lub are pretty dense. IMO the opening sentence explains it pretty clearly though. *'The least upper bound, or "lub", of a set of reference types is a shared supertype that is more specific than any other shared supertype.'*

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't have declared any variable because I'd never have used that form. But certifications, you know...

Comment: @Radiodef: I was looking for the definition, but couldn't find it... Where is it? (I've read it before, but can't find it now...)

Comment: Lub is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4 (Not sure why the conditional expression doesn't link to it since it's referenced so much there.)

Comment: @LuigiCortese: I agree that the book seems to be confusing here.

Answer (score 10):

Both alternatives of a ternary must be of the same type. The only common type for Integer and String is Object, so the operands are both cast to Object and the type of the ternary is determined at *compile* time to be Object.

The compiler then statically binds to the method with the Object parameter.

It matters not that *logically* the result of the ternary is determinable at compile time - the compiler doesn't work that way. It deals with expressions and types. It must first resolve the *type* of the ternary expression, not its *value*, and to do that it must first find a common type for the operands.

Comment: The key point here is that resolution of overloaded methods happens at compile time.

Comment: Well, the type of a conditional expression is determined on the basis of the type of the third and second operands, wich can actually be different

Answer (score 0):

This is, I suppose, in addition to the other answers. (Or, particularly, for anyone that wants to understand the pedantic answer.)

The result of a ternary conditional for reference types ends up to be `lub(trueType, falseType)`, so in this particular case, it's `lub(Integer, String)`. [`lub` is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4):

> The *least upper bound*, or "lub", of a set of reference types is a shared supertype that is more specific than any other shared supertype [...].

To understand `lub`, we could do a sort of "scratch" version of the algorithm for simple types as follows.

First, make a table for each type. In one column, write down the superclass hierarchy, and in another column, write down all the implemented interfaces:

```
+------------------------+------------------------+
|      Integer           |       String           |
+------------------------+---------+--------------+
| classes |  interfaces  | classes |  interfaces  |
+------------------------+---------+--------------+
| Object  | Serializable | Object  | Serializable |
| Number  | Comparable   | String  | Comparable   |
| Integer |              |         | CharSequence |
+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+
```

(The actual algorithm would lump classes and interfaces together as just "supertypes".)

Now:

- strike out all the superclasses, starting from the bottom, until you meet the superclass which is common.
- strike out all the interfaces which are not shared.

```
+------------------------+------------------------+
|      Integer           |       String           |
+------------------------+---------+--------------+
| classes |  interfaces  | classes |  interfaces  |
+------------------------+---------+--------------+
| Object  | Serializable | Object  | Serializable |
| Number  | Comparable   | String  | Comparable   |
| Integer |              |         | CharSequence |
+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+
```

`lub` is now the intersection type given by that common superclass and the shared interfaces:

```
lub(Integer, String) =
    Object & Serializable & Comparable
```

Except that `lub` is a bit more complicated here because of `Comparable`. Technically, `lub(Integer, String)` yields an infinite type because we need to do `lub(Integer, String)` again (infinitely) for the type argument to `Comparable`:

```
lub(Integer, String) =
    Object & Serializable & Comparable<? extends lub(Integer, String)>
```

The type of the conditional `(boolean ? Integer : String)` is then the type which is the result of applying capture conversion to `lub(Integer, String)` (yikes!).

The `foo(Object)` overload gets picked because it's the most applicable to this type.

A few other interesting things about this:

- If we added an overload `foo(Serializable)`, it will get picked because `Serializable` is more specific than `Object`.
- If we added two overloads `foo(Serializable)` and `foo(Comparable<?>)`, we will get an ambiguity error.